# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una validación de dominio en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estoy creando una plataforma web en laravel, y necesito que al momento de que los usuarios se registren mediante su correo únicamente permita los correos con un dominio en específico, por ejemplo "@misitio.es", he estado investigando un poco pero no he logrado encontrar mucha información, existe algún método o funcionalidad en laravel que me permita lograr esto?

Comment: Regex y validate investiga al respecto

Comment: un ejemplo de whitelist https://stackoverflow.com/a/15098661/1423096, un ejemplo de dominio válido (dns y mx válidos) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863956/1423096 ejemplo regex y laravel rules: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29720862/1423096